# Dynamic loading on text in FlipView with Next and Previous

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Problem:

I have more than 10,000 records in database, if first 50 records are showing in gridview and user clicked in 40th record and 40th record get displayed in flipview, than how can we dynamically load (record number 39,38,37.. soon ) using previous button and  (record number 41,42,43.. soon ) using Next button of flipview.

In other words 
I want to show these records in flipview with next and previous button.

Could someone suggest me how can I do this using xaml and c#.

Thanks in advance.

Ck Nitin

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a collection class that implements [`ISupportIncrementalLoading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx). I think what you are looking for is [data virtualizaiton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx).